# What the query to display all data on my table in uppercase?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I just try use

```
SELECT UPPER(*) FROM TABLE
```

but it didn't work

Comment: You need to go column by column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use the sentence UPPER for each varchar or char field in your table.
For example:

```
SELECT UPPER(Name), UPPER(LastName), UPPER(CityName)  FROM ClientsTable
```

On this way you obtain the data in uppercase.